# Trigger reverses the changes made - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm working on an E-commerce system where I have an order table that stores all the information regarding an order. The orders go through different stages: Open, Verified, In Process, etc. And I'm keeping counts of these orders at different stages e.g. Open Orders 95, Verified 5, In Process 3, etc.

When a new order is inserted in the table, I have a trigger that increments the Open Orders by 1. Similarly, I have a trigger for updates which checks the order's previous stage and the next to decrement and increment accordingly.

The INSERT trigger is working fine as described above. But the UPDATE trigger has a weird behavior that it makes the desired changes to the Counts but then reverses the changes for some reason.

For instance, upon changing the status of an order from Open to Verified, the ideal behavior would be to decrement Open Orders by 1 and increment Verified Orders by 1. The trigger currently performed the desired action but then for some reason restores the previous value.

Here's a snippet of my trigger where I check if the order previously belonged to the Open status and is now being updated to Verified status:

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN

DECLARE @orderID VARCHAR(MAX) -- orderID of the order that is being updated
DECLARE @storeID VARCHAR(MAX) -- storeID of the store the order belongs to

SELECT TOP 1
    @orderID = i.id,
    @storeID = i.storeID
FROM
    inserted AS i
    INNER JOIN deleted AS d
        ON i.id = d.id

-- IF from Open Order
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
        deleted
    WHERE
        orderStatus = 'Open' AND
        id = @orderID
)
BEGIN
    -- IF to Verified Order
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            inserted
        WHERE
            orderStatus = 'Verified' AND
            id = @orderID
    )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE order_counts
        SET 
            open_orders = open_orders - @@ROWCOUNT,
            verified_orders = verified_orders + @@ROWCOUNT
        WHERE storeID = @storeID
    END
END
```

**EDIT**: 
Here's some extra information which will be helpful in light of the first comment on the question:
I have a lot of records in the table so using `COUNT()` again and again has a lot of impact on the overall performance. This is why I'm keeping counts in a separate table. Also, I've written the trigger in a way that it handles both single record/multi record changes. I only check one row because I know in case of multiple records they will all be going through the same change of status. Hence, the decrement/increment of `@@ROWCOUNT`

Comment: Your trigger is broken for other reasons - `inserted` and `deleted` are pseudo-tables that can contain 0, 1, or *multiple* rows (depending on how many rows were affected by the original `UPDATE` statement). Your trigger is selecting values from *one* of those rows and *ignoring* the remaining rows. Is there a reason why you're maintaining *calculable* data manually anyway? (i.e. a `COUNT()` query against the orders table will always be *correct*, so is there a reason for avoiding that?)

Comment: I have a lot of records in the table so using `COUNT()` again and again has a lot of impact on the overall performance. This is why I'm keeping counts in a separate table. Also, I've written the trigger in a way that it handles both single record/multi record changes. I only check one row because I know in case of multiple records they will all be going through the same change of status. Hence, the decrement/increment of @@ROWCOUNT

Comment: _I know in case of multiple records they will all be going through the same change of status_  HAHA - no you assume. And you assume only because that is how you currently work with the data **at this point in time**. You also assume that @@rowcount is correct in all situations. It is [not](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/30dc5a24-d85b-4a37-9e7a-960e95326ddb/trigger-on-merge-statement?forum=transactsql)

Comment: Yes, I realized after the first few tests that `@@ROWCOUNT` isn't reliable at all, which is why I'm using one extra query to grab the number of rows in both `inserted` and `deleted` tables, and that is what I'm using in place of `@@ROWCOUNT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can tolerate a slightly different representation of the order counts, I'd strongly suggest using an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views) instead<sup>1</sup>:

```
create table dbo.Orders (
    ID int not null,
    OrderStatus varchar(20) not null,
    constraint PK_Orders PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
go
create view dbo.OrderCounts
with schemabinding
as
    select
        OrderStatus,
        COUNT_BIG(*) as Cnt
    from
        dbo.Orders
    group by OrderStatus
go
create unique clustered index IX_OrderCounts on dbo.OrderCounts (OrderStatus)
go
insert into dbo.Orders (ID,OrderStatus) values
(1,'Open'),
(2,'Open'),
(3,'Verified')
go
update dbo.Orders set OrderStatus = 'Verified' where ID = 2
go
select * from dbo.OrderCounts
```

Results:

```
OrderStatus          Cnt
-------------------- --------------------
Open                 1
Verified             2
```

This has the advantage that, whilst behind the scenes SQL Server is doing something very similar to running triggers, this code has been debugged thoroughly and is correct.

---

In your current attempted trigger, one further reason why the trigger is currently broken is that [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql) isn't "sticky" - it doesn't remember the number of rows that were affected by the original `UPDATE` when you're running other statements inside your trigger that also set `@@ROWCOUNT`.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can always stack a non-indexed view atop this view and perform a `PIVOT` if you really want the counts in a single row and in multiple columns.

Comment: I appreciate the effort. I really do. But I should point out that in the code I shared, the `OrderStatus` column isn't something real and is just to give you an idea of how things should work. I actually have to check multiple columns with different kinds of values to determine the current status and it's quite complex. The schema isn't well designed to be honest. So I'm actually hoping for an answer to the question as to why the trigger is behaving this way. Why is it reversing the changes that are being made? I'm certain it runs only once then why are the changes not being kept?

Comment: Then please try to create an [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, rather than showing us a *snippet* that you assume contains the source of the problem.

Comment: Turns out you were right and the issue was with `@@ROWCOUNT`. It somehow got past the first condition `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0` but was always zero upon multiple tests. I'm counting the rows using `COUNT()` now.

Comment: I am marking your answer as correct, as I believe it probably would be the right way to approach the problem as a whole, had the database been designed properly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is the use of @@ROWCOUNT multiple times while in reality once the results from @@ROWCOUNT is fetched, the results are cleared. Instead get the results into variable and use that variable across the trigger. Check the below scenario for the same.

```
CREATE DATABASE Test

USE Test

CREATE TABLE One
(
   ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

GO
CREATE TRIGGER TR_One ON One FOR INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

PRINT @@ROWCOUNT

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT

END


UPDATE One
SET Name = 'Name4'
WHERE ID = 3
```

RESULTS :-

The Print @@ROWCOUNT statement would give a value of 1, where as the select @@ROWCOUNT would give the value of 0

Comment: **VERY USEFUL INFORMATION**
This is actually quite useful information as I myself couldn't understand, at first, as to why `@@ROWCOUNT` was behaving so weirdly that it skipped the first `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN` check but then was zero in every other place I was using it. 
So thanks for that bit of information.